# On click <select> send form - multiple "select" object

Tags: jquery, html

I have FORM includes only one  object. When I change select to another value, continues jquery script and send POST data to php script. Works fine.  But if I read some data from mysql database - using cycle while{ }  ... N  objects are on html page ... and jquery function does not work

This is functional code with one SELECT - and works well.
When I add more SELECTs (after first part of code example), and click on first SELECT, also works. But when I click and change another one SELECT, nothing happened.

```
<form action="" method="POST">
<select name="role" id="roleId">
  <option label="test" value="1"> test  </option>
  <option label="test2" value="2"> test2  </option>
  <option label="test3" value="3"> test3  </option>
</select>
</form>

$("#roleId").on("change", function() {
    var idSdot = this.value;
    $.post("php-script.php", {id: idS}, function ( data ){
      alert(data);
    }, "html");
});

----------------------------------------------
more SELECTS on html :

<form action="" method="POST">
<select name="role" id="roleId">
  <option label="test" value="1"> test  </option>
  <option label="test2" value="2"> test2  </option>
  <option label="test3" value="3"> test3  </option>
</select>

<select name="role" id="roleId">
  <option label="test" value="4"> test  </option>
  <option label="test2" value="5"> test2  </option>
  <option label="test3" value="6"> test3  </option>
</select>


<select name="role" id="roleId">
  <option label="test" value="7"> test  </option>
  <option label="test2" value="8"> test2  </option>
  <option label="test3" value="9"> test3  </option>
</select>

</form>
```

how I should update FORM and jquery part? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Each select element must have different id, base on your ex. you are using roleId for all selects and that's why (Should be different ID for each select)

Answer (score 0):

Add a class value to each select list (class=“role”)

Then modify your jquery change function to listen by class and not ID

$(".role").on("change", function()

This is going to tell it that any element with that class should trigger the function.

By default IDs for elements are supposed to be unique so it is only triggering on the first element where the ID is found.

For Example your html changes to:

```
    <form action="" method="POST">
        <select name="role" id="roleId" class="role">
            <option label="test" value="1"> test  </option>
            <option label="test2" value="2"> test2  </option>
            <option label="test3" value="3"> test3  </option>
        </select>
        <select name="role" id="roleId2" class="role">
            <option label="test" value="4"> test  </option>
            <option label="test2" value="5"> test2  </option>
            <option label="test3" value="6"> test3  </option>
        </select>


        <select name="role" id="roleId3" class="role">
            <option label="test" value="7"> test  </option>
            <option label="test2" value="8"> test2  </option>
            <option label="test3" value="9"> test3  </option>
        </select>
    </form>
```

and you JS changes to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".role").on("change", function () {
        alert(this.value)
    });
</script>
```

Comment: thank you very much, this is it! So stupid, I forgot for class instead ID